# Defer variable assignment until file present or rule executed in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bioinformatics

I have a Makefile which downloads data from a biological database. Given a project number it should first download a file containing all the run information about that project, then extract accession numbers from the information, then download in parallel the FASTQ files associated with those accession numbers. My problem is that I cannot get the variable FASTQ to be deferred until after run.txt and sra.txt have been downloaded. I have tried combinations of order-only prerequisites and .SECONDEXPANSION but still cannot get it to work. Is it even possible?

```
# Project
PROJECT := PRJNA257197

# Download
.SECONDEXPANSION:
FASTQ = $(patsubst %, %.fastq, $(shell cat sra.txt))
download: $$(FASTQ) | run.txt sra.txt

%.fastq: sra.txt
    # Download FASTQ files
    fastq-dump $*

sra.txt: run.txt
    # Extract SRA accession numbers
    cat $^ | cut -f 1 -d ',' | grep SRR | tr '\n' ' ' > $@ 

run.txt:
    # Download run information
    esearch -db sra -query $(PROJECT) | efetch -format runinfo > $@
```

Comment: You don't have secondary expansion enabled in that snippet. You also don't use the `download` target anywhere. Can you please provide a complete and accurate makefile that represents one of your attempts. That being said you aren't going to be able to have make know about targets that can't be determined until after their prerequisites are processed. You have to work the other way. You need to get the prereq and then you can handle determining the targets that depend on it from that (generated included makefiles can be useful here).

Comment: @EtanReisner My apologies, I have added secondary expansion. The download target is the first target in the makefile so by default it executes when I run make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you want something more like this (comments inline):

```
# Project
PROJECT := PRJNA257197

# Include the fastqs.mk makefile.
include fastqs.mk

# Default target is all the fastq files.
all: $(FASTQS)

%.fastq: sra.txt
    # Download FASTQ files
    fastq-dump $*

# Create the fastqs.mk file from sra.txt.
fastqs.mk: sra.txt
    sed 's.*/FASTQS+=&.fastq/' $< > $@

sra.txt: run.txt
    # Extract SRA accession numbers
    cat $^ | cut -f 1 -d ',' | grep SRR | tr '\n' ' ' > $@ 

run.txt:
    # Download run information
    esearch -db sra -query $(PROJECT) | efetch -format runinfo > $@
```

Assuming each `.fastq` file has a matching bare file (i.e. `foo.fastq` -> `foo`) then you probably want this as the pattern target instead.

```
%.fastq: % sra.txt
```

The magic here is in that included makefile. Specifically that make is smart enough to notice when it needs to build an included makefile and restart processing after that has been done. See [How Makefiles Are Remade](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) in the manual for more details.